# Null Pointer Exception preparing Audio Player

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I am preparing a small audio player, and showing list of audio songs from device, but whenever i do tap on any of the song to play, everytime getting error.

Full **Logcat**:

```
06-10 15:52:28.440: W/dalvikvm(3732): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e0d2a0)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3699)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3694)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     ... 11 more
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     at com.example.syncing.MainActivity.songPicked(MainActivity.java:98)
06-10 15:52:28.450: E/AndroidRuntime(3732):     ... 14 more
06-10 15:52:38.065: I/Process(3732): Sending signal. PID: 3732 SIG: 9
```

check my complete source code **MainActivity.java:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayerControl {

    //song list variables
    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    private ListView songView;

    //service
    private MusicService musicSrv;
    private Intent playIntent;
    //binding
    private boolean musicBound=false;

    //controller
    private MusicController controller;

    //activity and playback pause flags
    private boolean paused=false, playbackPaused=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //retrieve list view
        songView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.song_list);
        //instantiate list
        songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        //get songs from device
        getSongList();
        //sort alphabetically by title
        Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
            public int compare(Song a, Song b){
                return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
            }
        });
        //create and set adapter
        SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

        //setup controller
        setController();
    }

    //connect to the service
    private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MusicBinder binder = (MusicBinder)service;
            //get service
            musicSrv = binder.getService();
            //pass list
            musicSrv.setList(songList);
            musicBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            musicBound = false;
        }
    };

    //start and bind the service when the activity starts
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(playIntent==null){
            playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
            bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(playIntent);
        }
    }

    //user song select
    public void songPicked(View view){
        musicSrv.setSong(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
        musicSrv.playSong();
        if(playbackPaused){
            setController();
            playbackPaused=false;
        }
        controller.show(0);
    }

    //method to retrieve song info from device
    public void getSongList(){
        //query external audio
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
        //iterate over results if valid
        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            } 
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        if(musicSrv!=null && musicBound && musicSrv.isPng())
            return musicSrv.getPosn();
        else return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        if(musicSrv!=null && musicBound && musicSrv.isPng())
            return musicSrv.getDur();
        else return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        if(musicSrv!=null && musicBound)
            return musicSrv.isPng();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        playbackPaused=true;
        musicSrv.pausePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int pos) {
        musicSrv.seek(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        musicSrv.go();
    }

    //set the controller up
    private void setController(){
        controller = new MusicController(this);
        //set previous and next button listeners
        controller.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playNext();
            }
        }, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playPrev();
            }
        });
        //set and show
        controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.song_list));
        controller.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void playNext(){
        musicSrv.playNext();
        if(playbackPaused){ 
            setController();
            playbackPaused=false;
        }
        controller.show(0);
    }

    private void playPrev(){
        musicSrv.playPrev();
        if(playbackPaused){
            setController();
            playbackPaused=false;
        }
        controller.show(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        paused=true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(paused){
            setController();
            paused=false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        controller.hide();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(playIntent);
        musicSrv=null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Line number 98 is:   musicSrv.setSong(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));

Comment: Either `'view'`, `'view.getTag()'`, or `'musicSrv'` is `'NULL'`.

Comment: Check your xml- have it "songPicked" in onClick event?
Why are you not using view.getId()?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set tag so view doesn't have it. You are getting null on view.getTag().toString()

Or put somewhere setTag to that view or check before calling if it is null:

```
if(view.getTag() != null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This should be comment, not answer.

Comment: Now it should be an answer